# How can I convert .py to .exe with an app?

Tags: python, type-conversion

I'm currently converting a Python file, which app I made for fun and has no .dll.

I have tried many ways like *pip*, *pyinstaller* and its result is not recognized.

I tried to environment variables in some videos on YouTube but still not work.

I saw an app that can convert python files but it's too old only for python 2.6. So what can I do now? I want a portable app that can convert python files to executable files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try the app [Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus).  This app will read a python script and convert it into an app.  It works on shell scripts as well. The app is free.